# Want to HIDE/REMOVE screen menu bar

Tags: java, macos, netbeans, screen, menubar

I have written a java app using NetBeans 7.2 under Os X 10.8.2 on a 2012 Mac Book Pro and I have decided I want the screen menubar removed or hidden since there is no easy way of editing the screen menu bar for my java app. I have searched and searched on the screen menu bar but I have not found anything showing how to: edit or hide. The only information I have come up with, using NetBeans is how to combine my JMenuBar into the screen menu bar and the examples for that didn't work.

If someone can point me into a good direction for editing the contents of the Screen Menu Bar I would be more then happy to use it. But if there is no easy way of doing this without re-writing the source code with an override then I will stay with my own menu on the form and hide or remove the Screen Menu Bar if this can be done.

[image]

Comment: Pleas add a link to your screenshot. If it is OK, somebody can include it in your question.

Comment: I just created a small web site to house my screen caps for the purpose of programming. The screen cap I spoke of above is: http://kieferthomas.webs.com/apps/photos/photo?photoid=169301928

Comment: I've included your screenshot.

Comment: Thanks for the info duskwuff for the screen menu bar not being able to be removed. The code of: System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true"); has worked for me after removing the MotifLookAndFeel setting. Previously the useScreenMenu bar would not be acknowleged

Comment: Thanks for editing my post and adding the pic Tichodroma.

Comment: Now can anyone tell me of a easy way to edit the screen menu in question with NetBeans... ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. The system menubar is a shared user interface element — you can only hide it if you're running full screen, at which point you end up with no menu bar at all.

You should really look into getting your application's menu bar to not appear in the window, as this is not an expected user interface idiom on Mac OS X. If you are not doing so already, this code may help:

```
System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
```

If that doesn't do it, there are a number of questions in the "Related" sidebar with information that may help.